# why cant i install ImageTk

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm getting into Tkinter and I'm trying to put images into the windows it makes, but wherever I search the internet all I find is that I need a module called ImageTk. I've tried installing this module and it doesn't work, I've got PIL and Pillow installed but ImageTk just won't install and I have no idea why.

I'm relatively new to Tkinter and my understanding of it is limited, so I'm sorry if it's an obvious problem.

Whenever I try to install I get the following:

> Selecting previously unselected package python3-pil.imagetk:armhf.
>   dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package
>   'qdbus' is missing final newline E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned
>   an error code (2)

Comment: what have you tried, what errors are you getting?

Comment: ImageTk is part of PIL. If you have installed Pillow correctly you can import it with `from PIL import Image, ImageTk`

Comment: Yeah ive tried that but it says: ImortError: cannot imort name 'ImageTk'

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-imaging
sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk` is what i found elsewhere, as it said you need to install ImageTk separately from PIL. that may have changed however

Answer (score 3):

1. Install Python Imaging with Tkinter support:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-imaging-tk
   ```
2. In the code:

   ```
   from PIL import ImageTk, Image
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Next advice helped me, after that I was able to import ImageTk from PIL:

```
# python 2
sudo apt-get install python-imaging python-pil.imagetk
# python 3
sudo apt-get install python3-pil python3-pil.imagetk
```

reference:
*https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/how+to+install+imagetk+in+python*